# Как проще реализовать аналог QSqlQueryModel, получающий данные не из базы, а из XML файла?

Tags: c++, qt

Дано:

на форме есть таблица `tableViewDocuments` типа `TableView`, для которой в качестве DataSet используется

```
QSqlQueryModel* pMdl = p_DB_PostgressProcessor->CreateOutPutDocList(Id);
ui.tableViewDocuments->setModel( pMdl );
```

где функция `CreateOutPutDocList()` имеет такую реализацию

```
QSqlQueryModel* DB_PostgressProcessor::CreateOutPutDocList(const QString& id)
{
       QString queryStr = "SELECT doc_number, name, date, description FROM bd_fp.document WHERE 
                           id=:id ORDER BY name;";

       QSqlQueryModel* pMdl = new QSqlQueryModel();
       QSqlQuery query(m_DB);

       query.prepare(queryStr);

       query.bindValue(":id", id);

       if (!query.exec())
       {  
            QSqlError err = query.lastError();
            mLogger.AddMessage(err.text());
            return pMdl;
       }

       pMdl->setQuery(query);

       return pMdl;
   }
```

Все прекрасно работает. Однако, теперь возникла необходимость создать автономное приложение без базы данных, в котором в роли источника данных используется ХМL-файл.

Вопрос - как проще это сделать с минимальными переделками ?

Прежде чем писать с нуля свой класс аналог `QSqlQueryModel`, производный от `QAbstractItemModel`, берущий данные из XML-файла и поддержвающий всю функциональность `QSqlQueryModel`, хотелось бы послушать советы умных людей - возможно, что это все уже сделано, и как они решали аналогичные проблемы.

Редактирование данных в таблице не требуется, она используется только для просмотра. Ограничений на структуру XML-файла нет, его можно сделать таким, как надо.

Comment: думаю самым простым и верным будет как раз таки реализовать класс производный от QAbstractItemModel

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, спасибо, я тоже склоняюсь, что лучше один раз потратить время и решить проблему в источнике, чем переделывать таблицы на многих формах. Мне кажется, что аналогичная проблема возникала у многих - нет ли где уже готового класса или примера, производного от QAbstractItemModel класса забирающего данные из XML-файла, либо примера реализации аналогичного класса, которую можно взять за основу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку готового решения не нашлось, то сделал собственную реализацию аналога `QSqlQueryModel`, которая берет данные не из базы, а из `XML-файла`. Я назвал ее `BaseTableModelByXML`. Сразу оговорюсь, поскольку для меня важным было сделать все очень быстро, то в качестве базового класса я взял не `QSqlQueryModel`, а `QAbstractTableModel`, заменив всюду приведение в исходной программной системе от `QSqlQueryModel` на `BaseTableModelByXML`, хотя без этого можно было обойтись в случаи наследования `QSqlQueryModel`. Ниже моя реализация, возможно она кому-нибудь поможет:

```
#pragma once
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QList>

class BaseTableModelByXML :
public QAbstractTableModel
{
public:
       Q_OBJECT

public:
       BaseTableModelByXML();
       ~BaseTableModelByXML();

      //Абстрактные функции базового класса, которые должны быть реализованы
      int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
      int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
      QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;

      QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const;
      bool setHeaderData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, const QVariant 
                          &value, int role = Qt::EditRole);

      QSqlRecord record(int row) const;

      //Этих функций нет QAbstractTableModel - она добавлена для упрощения формирования списка записей типа QSqlRecord при их формировании из XML
      QList <QSqlRecord> getRecords();
      void addRecord(QSqlRecord rec);


protected:
    //Заголовки колонок
    QList <QString>  lstColumnsHdr;
    //Список записей. Дабы ничего не переделывать в исходной системе они имеют тип QSqlRecord
    QList <QSqlRecord>  lstRecords;
};
```

Реализация класса:

```
#include "BaseTableModelByXML.h"
#include <QSqlField>


BaseTableModelByXML::BaseTableModelByXML()  {}

BaseTableModelByXML::~BaseTableModelByXML()
{
    lstRecords.clear();
}

int BaseTableModelByXML::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
      return lstRecords.count();
}

int BaseTableModelByXML::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
     if (lstRecords.count() == 0) return 0;
     return lstRecords[0].count();
}

QVariant BaseTableModelByXML::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
      QVariant value;
      if (!index.isValid())
                  return value;

      QSqlRecord rec = lstRecords[index.row()];
      QString fName = rec.fieldName(index.column());
      QSqlField fld = rec.field(fName);

     switch ( role)  //switch сделан "на вырост" - ролей много, в частности в этом месте можно менять цвет ячейки в зависимости от ее содержимого
     {
         case Qt::DisplayRole:
               return fld.value();
          default:
               return value;
     }

     return value;
 }


 QVariant BaseTableModelByXML::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
 {
     if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
         return QVariant();

     if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
         return lstColumnsHdr[section];   //Отображаем имя колонки
     else
         return QString("%1").arg(section+1); //Отображаемый номер строки
}

bool BaseTableModelByXML::setHeaderData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    lstColumnsHdr.append(value.toString());  //Это упрощенный вариант, адаптированный к исходному коду, где происходит вызов этой функции. 
     return true;
}


QSqlRecord BaseTableModelByXML::record(int row) const
{
     if (lstRecords.count() == 0 || row >= lstRecords.count() || row < 0)
     {
          QSqlRecord rtc;
          return rtc;
     }

     return lstRecords[row];
}


void BaseTableModelByXML::addRecord(QSqlRecord rec)
{
      lstRecords.append(rec);
}

QList <QSqlRecord> BaseTableModelByXML::getRecords()
{
     return lstRecords;
}
```

Ну и в завершении, пример заполнения экземпляра класса `BaseTableModelByXML` из XML-файла. В моем случае за работу с разными источниками данных отвечает классы, производные от некого класса `DataProcessor` и, в случаи `XML`, - это класс `XML_Processor`. Опуская детали, в него загружается исходный XML-файл, который заносится в элемент doc и затем XML преобразуется в различные экземпляры классов BaseTableModelByXML. Ниже упрощенный пример:

```
BaseTableModelByXML* XML_Processor::createDocListModel( int *pLastColumn)
{
     if (!FileIsLoaded)     return 0;

     BaseTableModelByXML *pMdl = new BaseTableModelByXML();

     int pos = 0;
     pMdl->setHeaderData(pos++, Qt::Horizontal, "Id");
     pMdl->setHeaderData(pos++, Qt::Horizontal, RussianForQT5("Название"));
     pMdl->setHeaderData(pos++, Qt::Horizontal, RussianForQT5("Комментарий"));
     *pLastColumn = pos - 1;

     QDomNodeList lst = doc.elementsByTagName("DocSection"); //doc - это объект типа QDomDocument, куда предварительно был загружен XML-файл

     for (int i = 0; i < lst.count(); ++i)
     {
          QDomElement element = lst.at(i).toElement();

          if (!element.isNull())
          {
                QString id = element.attribute("id", "");
                QString name = element.attribute("name", "");
                QString description = element.attribute("description", "");

                QSqlField f1(QSqlField("Id", QVariant::String));
                f1.setValue(id);

                QSqlField f2(QSqlField("name", QVariant::String));
                f2.setValue(name);

                QSqlField f3(QSqlField("description", QVariant::String));
                f3.setValue(description);

                QSqlRecord rec;
                rec.append(f1);
                rec.append(f2);
                rec.append(f3);

                pMdl->addRecord(rec);
          }
      }

  return pMdl;
 }
```